# Deleting capital letters in a C-String

Tags: c++

write a function that returns no value to delete capital letters in a C-string

void erase(char* a) 
{
    char* targetp = sourcep;

```
while (*sourcep != '\0')
{
    if (isupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(a)== false)     
    {
        *targetp++ = *sourcep;
    }
    a++;
}
*a='\0';
}
```

Comment: If you debugged your code and followed it carefully, you should have seen that removing a character would skip over the next character, all due to you collapsing the string.

Comment: Unrelated to your core question, but relevant: [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a++` should **not** be invoked if you have deleted a letter. Use an `else` to implement that.

Else you'll skip over letters, and your algorithm will fail for cases where there are consecutive capitals.

Also `*p != '\0'` can be abbreviated to simply `*p`. Not to everyone's taste but it's what I do.

Comment: *"Use an else to implement that. Else you'll skip over letters"* - Please never edit it out :D

Comment: Oh, if I don't use the else statement, it also shifts but also sometime skips over the capitals?

Comment: @Zach: Absolutely!

Answer (score 4):

You should not copy all the text every time you see a upper case letter. You simply skip the upper case letter and copy step by step. See the solution below. It's much faster!

```
void deleteCapitals(char* sourcep) //a function that only passes
{
    char* targetp = sourcep;

    while (*sourcep != '\0')
    {
        if (!isupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(*sourcep)))     
        {
            *targetp++ = *sourcep;
        }
        sourcep++;
    }
    *targetp='\0';
}
```

Comment: To nitpick, you have to replace one of the two pointers by `a`, since "only one additional variable is allowed"

Comment: @coyotte508: I did the oppsite and replace a in the declaration to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

Everytime two upper case letters are next to each other, you give a pass to the second one.

An alternative to @Bathsheba's solution is to use a `while` instead of `if`:

```
while (isupper(*a))
{
    for (char* p = a; *p != '\0'; p++)
    {
        *p = *(p + 1);
    }
}
```

That way if `*a` is still uppercase after the reassignment, it does it again.

Comment: This potentially invokes UB. See [Do I need to cast to unsigned char before calling toupper?](//stackoverflow.com/q/21805674)